# Can I retrofit ground under NEC 2008?

Tags: electrical, wiring, code-compliance

The state of Indiana still <s>[seems to be](https://www.in.gov/dhs/files/NEMA-Letter-Recommending-Updating-Indiana-Electrical-Code.pdf) (PDF)</s> *is* ([official state link](https://www.in.gov/dhs/fire-and-building-safety/fpbsc-rules/)) on NEC 2008. In NEC 2014, the provision to retrofit ground by running a separate ground wire from an outlet back to the panel or the nearest properly grounded circuit (on the same or larger wire size) was added in.

Since we haven't yet adopted the updated code, would I still be allowed to add in grounding this way or would it be considered a violation?

I live in a *very* small town, so I'm 100% certain that we haven't adopted any additions/amendments to code (also our level of inspection quality isn't the highest). Our county is somewhat uppity, but I don't think we would have adopted any amendments at the county level, either.

Comment: Would double check with locals, but doubt that using non adopted regulations is okay to use before hand.  Quite possible that showing locals the updates, they will give permission, but to do so without permission is not okay.

Comment: @crip659 it must be a little more subtle than that. Adopting innovations that are required by newer code and didn't exist when older code was written must surely be ok everywhere.  You wouldn't want mandatory proactive grandfathering, that would be horrendous and ridiculous.  The question is does 2008 explicitly forbid this?   It would be interesting to know what practices are allowed or even encouraged in code that were explicitly forbidden in prior versions.   I'm not disagreeing with your point, just thinking it can't be that blunt.

Answer (score 3):

When I was in Mishawaka many years back I asked a similar question and the inspector told me NO you have to use the version of code as adopted.

I would contact the building safety department and check with them they may point you to the amendments or just be rude like they were for me.

It may sound backwards not to adopt some parts of the modern code that in this case can make a dwelling much safer but that is how it was in the 80’s.

I did have a license but was visiting from another state and that also up set him but it was legal to help direct family members.

Comment: Thanks Ed. I'm closer to Indy, but I've been to Mishawaka more than once. I doubt our local inspector would care tremendously one way or the other - he's pretty lax, which is good, but bad. OTOH, we're going to add on a whole new panel with an addition this summer. It'll have _plenty_ of room for new circuits, so if he gives me grief, I'll just rewire, which kinda needs to happen anyway.

Comment: To tell the truth when I was there it was like the Stone Age compared to the states I lived and trained (Oregon and Washington). I bought a house that was wired 100% backwards white hot and black neutral. Found out the hard way switch off and touching what ended up to be hot, ok it was not that bad but a lot of fly by night contractors compared to my training.  my brother in laws home was a 20’s k&t I don’t remember the question but I rewired the house with a 60 main code back then for ~300$ Panel wire and boxes. I just did not like the inspector from south bend.